# Hide filter form when filter is limited to one active item

Tags: search

I have the following facets:

- School
- Location
- Grade

These are indexed from taxonomy fields and 'School' is multi value while 'Location' and 'Grade' are single value fields.

My facets are set to hide not display when empty and limited to one active item at a time.

The 'Location' and 'Grade' forms are hidden when one item is selected, I'll like to hide the 'School' form as well when it is active.

Any ideas, I was thinking of hook_form_alter and then disabling the form when it's active.